# does the Android Studio Emulator also emulate the spec and performance of the device?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing an app on a very powerful desktop machine. I need to know how it would perform on a phone. When running the app on the Android Studio Emulator, doe sth emulator also emulate the spec and performance of the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not an exact 1:1 simulator of existing device. It's emulator. And given the variety of existing devices it'd be rather problematic to have one that would exactly mimic specific device. If you need one, the I'd say that having physical device in hand would be the best approach, aside the emulator.